# Google Maps API identical examples: one renders, one doesn't

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

Here are two jsfiddles with identical code. [One](https://jsfiddle.net/5stxw2dw/2/) is a fork from Google Maps API's documentation, no changes. [The second](https://jsfiddle.net/wsmuh7uh/5/) is just copied and pasted into jsfiddle. The fork from Google renders as expected. The one I copied and pasted does not.

I used a diff checker, and it showed them as identical. What am I missing?

HTML

```
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDglJmtJY5078jjZOJZFNNMO7CJb5E3nE4&callback=initMap">


</script>
```

JS

```
// Note: This example requires that you consent to location sharing when
// prompted by your browser. If you see the error "The Geolocation service
// failed.", it means you probably did not give permission for the browser to
// locate you.

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
    zoom: 6
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({map: map});

  // Try HTML5 geolocation.
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var pos = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude
      };

      infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
      infoWindow.setContent('Location found.');
      map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
      handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    });
  } else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
  }
}

function handleLocationError(browserHasGeolocation, infoWindow, pos) {
  infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
  infoWindow.setContent(browserHasGeolocation ?
                        'Error: The Geolocation service failed.' :
                        'Error: Your browser doesn\'t support geolocation.');
}
```

CSS

```
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second fiddle, the JAVASCRIPT settings needs to have Load Type as `No wrap - in <body>`